# vs2008 syntax highlighting for il assembler

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting, intermediate-language

is there a way to get visual studio 2008 to do a nice syntax highlighting for the intermediate language?

Comment: MonoDevelop has support for IL syntax highlighting. I don't understand why IL is a second-class citizen for Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is:
http://dashingboy.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/masm-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, no. You could use ILIDE# (http://nida.se/ilide/)

It's a small editor for IL-ASM files, with intellisense support.

Comment: this editor looks pretty much what i'm looking for. Sadly it crashes everytime i try to open my .il file :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is a codeplex addin:
http://asmhighlighter.codeplex.com/